# Why do I get an error if I try to put values into a map in my view class?

Tags: java, scala, dictionary, playframework

I am trying to append values to a map in a scala class.

I have a generic map with question / answerList pairs in my controller class:

```
static Map<Question, List<Answer>> myMap = new HashMap<Question, List<Answer>>();

Question question1 = new Question("xyz", "Do Androids dream?", 127, "Marcus");
Answer answer11 = new Answer("zab", "xyz", "Only of electric sheep!", 70, "Sarah");

List<Answer> answerList1 = new ArrayList<Answer>();
answerList1.add(answer11);

// puts the question and its answers into the hashmap
myMap.put(question1, answerList1);

public static Result askQuestion(){
return ok(views.html.questionAnswer.render(myMap)); 
}
```

In my viewclass I add a new question / answer pair into the map:

```
@import model.Question
@import model.Answer

@(myMap: Map[Question, List[Answer]])

@main("Ask question"){
@myMap.put(new Question("id123", "questiontext", 34, "userID"), new List[Answer]);
}
```

But when I run the code the error page comes up, saying: "trait List is abstract; cannot be instantiated". Why cant I put a (question, List[answer]) pair into my map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get an error because, just as your error message states: you can not instantiate an abstract class.

You'll need to instantiate a subclass of it.

```
new List[Answer]
```

will never work. Instantiate a subclass that suits your needs.

Comment: I am a little bit confused now, isnt `List[Answer]` already a subclass of List[Object]?

Comment: @hamena314 `scala.collection.immutable.List` is an abstract class, so you cannot instantiate it. You can write `List[Answer](/*your elements*/)` to call the apply method of the **object** with the name `List`, or `Nil[Answer]` to create an empty `List[Answer]`. Also, make sure not to mix up `scala.collection.immutable.List` and `scala.util.List`... those are completly independent types. (you can however convert one to the other.

Comment: @hamena314 Furthermore: Yes, `scala.collection.immutable.List` is covariant in its generic parameter, so `List[Answer]` is a `List[Any]`. Note that this isn't the case for `java.util.List`, which is mutable, and hence invariant in its generic parameter.

Comment: So my java `HashMap<Question, List<Answer>>` gets converted into a scala map? If so, how can you create a `List[Answer]` in the scala viewclass `questionAnswer.scala.html`? Because using `Nil[Answer]` gives me the error `object Nil does not take type parameters`

Comment: @hamena314 I'm sorry, you are right, you only write `Nil` and type inference decides that it is in fact of type `List[Answer]`. The converstion between the collections doesn't happen automatically (though I don't know the play framework, so this might do the conversion for you). Have a look at [scala.collection.JavaConversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions$)

Comment: @KuluLimpa It seems as if the compiler cant infer the type of an empty list sometimes, so you need to tell him yourself. So this will work: `@myMap.put(new Question("id123", "questiontext", 34, "userID"), Nil: List[Answer]);`

Answer (score 0):

As [Stultuske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2636929/stultuske) and [Kulu Limpa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4041697/kulu-limpa) have pointed out you need to instantiate a subclass. This will work:

```
// Note: You need to tell the compiler which type Nill should use
@myMap.put(new Question("id123", "questiontext", 34, "userID"), Nil: List[Answer]);
```